# Query to Group By and Exclude from Multiple Lists

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a SQL table (Email_Campaigns) with a master list of campaigns we've run:

```
Name            DateSent
Campaign01    01/01/2011
Campaign02    01/15/2011
..
Campaign40    10/01/2011
```

I've got a list of customers (Email_Received) with their membership numbers and the campaigns they've received:

```
PK    MembershipNo    CampaignName
1           123456      Campaign01
2           123456      Campaign02
3           987654      Campaign05
4           111111      Campaign10
```

I've also got a master list of customer MembershipNo's (Customers)

**Question:** How do I write a query to list each campaign and count the number of customers who DID NOT receive that e-mail?  For example ('Received' column is only shown here for reference and isn't imperative as I know how to calculate that):

```
Name          Received    DidNotReceive
Campaign01        1000             9000
Campaign02        3000             7000
..
Campaign40         100             9900
```

Comment: To address a question below... Yes, there are certainly cases where Customers received multiple e-mail and that is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one standard SQL way to write this:

```
SELECT ec.Name, count(c.MembershipNo) AS DidNotReceive
  FROM Customers AS c
     , Email_Campaigns AS ec
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM Email_Received AS r
     WHERE er.CampaignName = ec.CampaignName
       AND er.MembershipNo = c.MembershipNo)
 GROUP BY ec.Name
 ORDER BY ec.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I asked because I previously had exactly what you had except for the "AND" clause... no wonder the query spun for 15+ minutes with no result. :-/

Comment: @hurleystylee: If your specific conditions allow for it, you should also try the answer of Joe Stefanelli, which might be considerably faster with big tables. Add in the `DISTINCT` I mentioned if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT er.CampaignName, 
       COUNT(*) AS Received, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers) - COUNT(*) AS DidNotReceive
    FROM Email_Received er
    GROUP BY er.CampaignName
    ORDER BY er.CampaignName;
```

This is at the very simplest level. There are probably additional considerations to take into account, such as whether or not a given customer was active at the time the campaign was distributed.

Comment: That should be faster than my answer. However, my answer also covers the case of duplicate entries in `Email_Received` (people could get multiple emails, by design or by mistake) - which has not been excluded in the question. Could be fixed with a COUNT (DISTINCT x). Not sure if that is allowed in tsql.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter T-SQL has `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`.